# How to dynamic colums value update one by one on same id in mongodb using asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have to Create a MongoDB connection and get records and update a single column value properly that working code.

```
 public bool UpdateContactDetail(string ContactId,string ColumnsValue, BsonDocument document)
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                MongoClient client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
                MongoServer objServer = client.GetServer();
                var DB = objServer.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
                var collection = DB.GetCollection(TableName);
                var searchQuery = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(ContactId));
                var sortBy = SortBy.Null;
                update = Update.Set("Column Name", ColumnsValue);
                collection.FindAndModify(searchQuery,sortBy, update);

                 success = true;
            }
            catch (MongoConnectionException) { return false; }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandling.InsertExceptionMessage("MongoDB", this.GetType().Name, 
                System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I have added for a loop because I want to do multiple columns values update in the same record. I do not want to give static columns names and why select id records deleted I don't understand.

```
 public bool UpdateContactDetail(string ContactId,string Taglist, BsonDocument document) // Columns Value and Taglist Updated
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                MongoClient client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
                MongoServer objServer = client.GetServer();
                var DB = objServer.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
                var collection = DB.GetCollection(TableName);
                var searchQuery = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(ContactId));
                var sortBy = SortBy.Null;

              **for (int i = 0; i < document.ElementCount; i++)
                {
                     update = Update.Set(document.ToArray()[i].Name, document.ToArray()[i].Value.ToString());
                     collection.FindAndModify(searchQuery,sortBy, update);
                }**

                success = true;
            }
            catch (MongoConnectionException) { return false; }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandling.InsertExceptionMessage("MongoDB", this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database and Collection Object should be initialized on every update. Try this code. It's will work defiantly.

```
public bool UpdateContactDetail(string ContactId,string ColumnsValue, BsonDocument document)
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {                                    
              MongoClient client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
              MongoServer objServer = client.GetServer();
            for (int i = 0; i < document.ElementCount; i++)
            {
              var DB = objServer.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
              var collection = DB.GetCollection("EmailContacts");
              var searchQuery = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(ContactId));
              var sortBy = SortBy.Null;
              var update = Update.Set(document.ToArray()[i].Name, document.ToArray()[i].Value.ToString());
              collection.FindAndModify(searchQuery, sortBy, update);
            }
            success = true;
            }
            catch (MongoConnectionException) { return false; }    
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandling.InsertExceptionMessage("MongoDB", this.GetType().Name, 
                System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then Vote me up!!